# If I were to add the axiom schema of (restricted) comprehension to my "reduced" set theory, would I be able to prove any new propositions?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Suppose I had the following axioms: extensionality, nullset, pairs, unions, and powerset. Would adding comprehension (the axiom of separation) allow me to prove any new propositions? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: Well, the question is, what exactly do you mean by "sets we are able to create"?  The idea may seem intuitively clear but it is not so clear what sort of precise statement you would want.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for the comment. I've updated the question.

Comment: How about something like "if there exists an infinite set $X$, then there exists a set containing exactly the infinite subsets of $X$"?

Comment: Or maybe simpler: "for all $x$, there exists a set containing exactly the proper subsets of $x$".

Comment: @DanielPhilpott New version is a much different question (but unlike like the old one, has a clear interpretation and a clean answer).

Comment: @DanielPhilpott By the way, the answer to your original question is (arguably) no, but as mentioned, there are some issues making this precise.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, but do you know the answer to the question as it stands? The new question is a lot broader, but it's probably the question I was really interested in to begin with. Since comprehension is a ZF axiom, it must add to the theory, but I'm wondering whether that is still the case without the axiom of infinity. Adding comprehension to the above axioms would seem intuitively to yield an equivalent theory.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks, but I didn't actually include the axiom of infinity in the question. With regard to your second example, it seems to me (intuitively) that for any (finite) set x, you can prove that there exists as set containing precisely the proper subsets of x without comprehension (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @DanielPhilpott Yes I noticed that you did not include infinity. But not including infinity is not the same as proving that no infinite sets exist. That's why I included "If there exists an infinite set $X$, then..." in my first example. The point of the second example is that since your theory does not settle the question of whether an infinite set exists, it cannot prove that "proper power sets" exist for all sets (since there are models with infinite sets whose "proper power sets" do not exist).

Comment: @Daniel The answer is yes, it’s strictly stronger, as Alex has indicated.  On a side note, separation is actually redundant in a lot of presentations of ZF, but it’s intuitively important and adds strength to weaker theories, so almost always kept as an axiom.

Comment: @DanielPhilpott The reason you find the opposite intuitive is probably has a lot to do with how you phrased your last question. You can indeed build all the hereditarily finite sets without separation from the axioms you mentioned (actually no need for power set). But this is very different from the sentences in the language you can prove. It might be instructive to compare to first order arithmetic: any old theory, whether as weak as Robinson arithmetic or strong as Peano arithmetic can 'build all natural numbers' but there can be a huge difference in strength.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the replies. I must admit I'm quite surprised that separation is kept as an axiom even if redundant.

Comment: @DanielPhilpott Separation is such a foundational idea that it would be hard to imagine not including it, even if technically replacement (usually) implies it. Same goes with pairing, which is also implied by replacement. (Plus we often want to think about weaker theories without replacement but with separation/pairing. Also, it is sometimes convenient to use weaker versions of replacement/union/pair/powerset that require separation to obtain full strength.) On a side note, null set is implied by separation and existence of any set (e.g. infinity implies this), but this one *is* omitted a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write $T$ for your "reduced set theory": extensionality, nullset, pairs, unions, and powerset. And let's write $\text{Inf}$ for the axiom of infinity and $\text{Comp}$ for the schema of comprehension.

Now for any sentence $\varphi$, just by basic logic, we have $$T+\text{Inf}\vdash \varphi \quad \text{if and only if} \quad T\vdash \text{Inf}\rightarrow \varphi.$$ And $$T+\text{Inf}+\text{Comp}\vdash \varphi \quad \text{if and only if} \quad T+\text{Comp}\vdash \text{Inf}\rightarrow \varphi.$$

I assume you agree that the schema of comprehension allows $T+\text{Inf}$ to prove new propositions. So if we let $\varphi$ be some sentence such that $T+\text{Inf}+\text{Comp}\vdash \varphi$ and $T+\text{Inf}\not\vdash \varphi$, then we have $T+\text{Comp}\vdash \text{Inf}\rightarrow \varphi$ and $T\not\vdash \text{Inf}\rightarrow \varphi$.

So yes, adding the schema of comprehension to $T$ does allow us to prove new propositions.

A more interesting question is whether the theory $T+\lnot\text{Inf}$ (with the *negation* of the axiom of infinity) proves all instances of the comprehension schema. I agree that intuitively it should... but this might be sensitive to exactly how one phrases the infinity axiom...

Comment: I’m not sure my intuition agrees that separation will be redundant if negation of inf is included. It would definitely hold in HF but don’t see why it should hold in a nonstandard model. Am I missing something?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My idea is to prove that every set is encoded by a natural number, via the [Ackerman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate), and then get comprehension by taking a set, coding it as a natural number, computing a new natural number coding the subset defined by a give formula, and getting the set coded by that new number. In nonstandard models, the natural numbers involved will be nonstandard, but that's ok. The issue is that I haven't thought through whether this coding goes through just using the axioms in the OP's theory.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh, I just noticed that the OP's theory excludes foundation. So the Ackerman coding is out the window. I expect $T + \lnot \text{Inf}$ won't prove the following instance of comprehension: $\forall x\, \exists y\, \forall z\, (z\in y\leftrightarrow (z\in x \land z\in z))$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks for the answer, I probably should've thought a bit more before rephrasing the question. I asked the initial question because I seemed to be able to prove the existence of any set of cardinality 0, 1, 2, 3... that I could imagine using only extensionality, nullset, pairs, and unions. (I've just started teaching myself a course on set theory which I wasn't able to get tutorials for - I haven't actually reached the axioms of foundation and replacement in the notes yet!)